# Need the correct logic when using LISTAGG

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
select id,LISTAGG(DISTINCT APN_OL,',')  AS APN_NEW 
from
(SELECT id, pid,
listagg(DISTINCT apn_nbr, ';') within GROUP(ORDER BY apn_nbr)as APN_OL
FROM
(SELECT max(pid) as pid,
                    f1.id,
                    apn_nbr,
                    date
FROM table1 f1
JOIN table2 f2
ON f1.process_id  = f2.process_id  
WHERE apn_nbr is not null AND id=1227521
GROUP BY id,apn_nbr,date)
GROUP BY id,pid;
```

When I try the below query, I'm getting records as mentioned below:

```
   ID         PID           APN_NBR
1227521 964306012133700     238885004,130050106,195050142,960109430
1227521 816449643060121     105450046,105450314,136010476,136150077
```

I want to display all the records for APN_NBR in a single row(ie.Records from Row 1 and Row 2 to be displayed in a single row. So I tried the below logic:

```
select id,LISTAGG(DISTINCT APN_OL,',')  AS APN_NEW 
from
(SELECT id, pid,
listagg(DISTINCT apn_nbr, ';') within GROUP(ORDER BY apn_nbr)as APN_OL
FROM
(SELECT max(pid) as pid,
                    f1.id,
                    apn_nbr,
                    date
FROM table1 f1
JOIN table2 f2
ON f1.process_id  = f2.process_id  
WHERE apn_nbr is not null AND id=1227521
GROUP BY id,apn_nbr,date)
GROUP BY id,pid)
GROUP BY id;
```

When I use the above query, I'm getting values for APN_NBR in a single row.

However I need to add pid in the SELECT statement in order to perform join operation with
another table. I need to join based on ID and PID columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you could move the second LISTAGG into the first (unless you want semi-comma seperated and comma seperated values, AND then make an array of the PID's and join to all the match rows like so:

```
select 
    a.id, 
    a.APN_OL as apn_new
    b.<stuff from pids stuff>
from
(
    SELECT 
        id, 
        array_agg(distinct pid) as pids,
        listagg(DISTINCT apn_nbr, ';') within GROUP(ORDER BY apn_nbr)as APN_OL
    FROM ( 
        SELECT 
            max(pid) as pid,
            f1.id,
            apn_nbr
        FROM table1 f1
        JOIN table2 f2
            ON f1.process_id = f2.process_id  
        WHERE apn_nbr is not null AND id = 1227521
        GROUP BY id, apn_nbr
    )
    GROUP BY id
) as A
JOIN table_with_pids_details as B 
    on ARRAY_CONTAINS(b.pid::variant, a.pids);
```

OR

you if the PID all have the same values, but you just need one, then ANY_VALUE() can be helpful.

```
select 
    a.id, 
    a.APN_OL as apn_new
    b.<stuff from pids stuff>
from
(
    SELECT 
        id, 
        ANY_VALUE(distinct pid) as random_pid,
        listagg(DISTINCT apn_nbr, ';') within GROUP(ORDER BY apn_nbr)as APN_OL
    FROM ( 
        SELECT 
            max(pid) as pid,
            f1.id,
            apn_nbr
        FROM table1 f1
        JOIN table2 f2
            ON f1.process_id = f2.process_id  
        WHERE apn_nbr is not null AND id = 1227521
        GROUP BY id, apn_nbr
    )
    GROUP BY id
) as A
JOIN table_with_pids_details as B 
    on b.pid = a.random_pid;
```